# Retrieve elements in array with the same value and group them to manipulate data in the group

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like below

```
 $crops = array(
  0 => array(
      'crop_name' => 'Maize',
      'crop_variety_name' => 'Longe 10H',
      'weeks' => array(
          9  => 11.200,
          10 => 14.700,
          11 => 12.300,
          12 => 4.300,
          14 => 8.500,
          16 => 18.800,
          17 => 10.600,
          20 => 10.000,
          30 => 7.000
     )
 ),
  1 => array(
     'crop_name' => 'Maize',
     'crop_variety_name' => 'Longe 5',
     'weeks' => array(
          15 => 15.400,
          16 => 4.700,
          19 => 11.000,
          20 => 3.000,
          21 => 5.000,
          29 => 2.000
     )
 ),
  2 => array(
     'crop_name' => 'Maize',
     'crop_variety_name' => 'VP Max',
     'weeks' => array(
          9 => 6.800,
          10 => 8.000,
          14 => 3.000,
          15 => 6.800,
          17 => 4.300,
          18 => 7.400,
          20 => 5.900,
          21 => 2.400,
          22 => 2.800,
          23 => 5.400,
          24 => 3.900
     )
 ),
  3 => array(
     'crop_name' => 'Rice',
    'crop_variety_name' => 'Superica 2',
    'weeks' => array(
         18 => 6.600,
         19 => 11.500,
         20 => 8.300,
         21 => 10.100,
         24 => 2.800
    )
),
 4 => array(
    'crop_name' => 'Soya',
    'crop_variety_name' => 'Soya N1',
    'weeks' => array(
         20 => 3.000
    )
),
 5 => array(
    'crop_name' => 'Soya',
    'crop_variety_name' => 'Soya N3',
    'weeks' => array(
         10 => 5.9,
         11 => 12.800,
         12 => 5.100,
         15 => 4.000,
         19 => 4.000,
         31 => 3.100
     )
   )
);
```

Different crops  `crop_name` have one or more varieties `crop_variety_name`. I want to retrieve the crops for example `'crop_name'=>'Maize' regardless of their crop varieties and then retrieve the weeks array and add all the values in the week array for each for the crop varieties such that I have an array like this

```
array(
    'Maize' => 195.2,
    'Rice' => 39.3
    'Soya' => 37.9)
```

Where the key is the `crop_name`  and the value is the total of the values in the the weeks array for the crop_varieties of each crop. The first array  can contain an arbitrary number of crops, crop_varieties and the weeks array can contain an arbitrary number of values. How can i go about this. For the crop names I tried this

```
   $crop_names = array();
          for($i = 0; $i < count($crops); $i++ ){
             array_push($crop_names, $crops[$i]['crop_name']);  
               }
               $crop_name = array_values(array_unique($crop_names));
```

This works for for crop_names but `array_unique` causes loss of data.

Comment: What loss of data? It removes duplicates but it still keeps one item of each kind.

Comment: @axiac It will keep the first key encountered for every value, and ignore all following keys.

Comment: There is no place in your code where you use the keys of `$crops`. By chance, it happens that the values you put in `$crop_names` use the same keys they have in `$crops`. This won't happen any more if you do, let's say `unset($crops[2])` before `$crop_names = array();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not match your requirement.

> I want to retrieve the crops for example `'crop_name'=>'Maize' regardless of their crop varieties and then retrieve the weeks array and add all the values in the week array for each for the crop varieties such that I have an array like this
>
> ```
> array(
>     'Maize' => 195.2,
>     'Rice' => 39.3
>     'Soya' => 37.9)
> ```

This is how the above requirement is translated into code:

```
$amounts = array();
foreach ($crops as $crop) {
    $name = $crop['crop_name'];
    if (! isset($amounts[$name])) {
        // This is the first time when this crop type is processed
        $amounts[$name] = 0;
    }
    // Add all the values in the week array regardless of varieties
    $amounts[$name] += array_sum($crop['weeks']);
}

// If you need the names in a separate list you can get it with array_keys()
$crop_names = array_keys($amounts);
```

Take a look at the [array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) section of the PHP manual for more ideas.

Comment: Yes it works perfectly. It is what I was trying to implement.